# Configuring django-userena

Tags: django, authentication, registration

for my new project I decided to use [django-userena](https://django-userena.org/)

I followed the instructions from [userena docs](http://docs.django-userena.org/en/latest/installation.html). However I'm getting this error :

> SiteProfileNotAvailable at /accounts/signin/
>
> No exception supplied

and don't know how to fix it. Please help !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You usually get a `SiteProfileNotAvailable` when Django can't find your profile. As documented in the "[Storing additional information about users](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users)", you need to define `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE` to point to the model of you profile.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this to work. Unfortunately the userena docs aren't very... descriptive when discussing how to properly set up `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE`. From reading your link, I created an app called 'accounts' and added something similar to their [MyProfile](http://docs.django-userena.org/en/latest/installation.html#installing-django-userena) to that models.py named `UserProfile`. Then in settings.py I set `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'accounts.UserProfile'`. However it throws a SiteProfileNotAvailable exception when I visit any URL on my site now.

Comment: Chris, I was just having the same problem, and figured I should share the solution in case someone else comes across this. For me the problem was that I forgot to `syncdb` after installing all these new apps. And then once I did that, I realized there were some typos and missing import statements in my `accounts/models.py` that it hadn't complained to me about. Once I fixed `models.py` and successfully `syncdb`'d, everything was fine.

Answer (score 7):

As wunki has aptly pointed out, it's important to define the `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE` in your settings.py file to point to your subclass of `UserenaBaseProfile` or `UserenaLanguageBaseProfile`.  As discussed in the userena tutorial, these are usually placed inside of the models.py file of your newly created 'accounts' project.

However, I've found that the `python manage.py runserver` will fail if you have already provided `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE`.  If you have provided `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE` and still receive a SiteProfileNotAvailable error (on every URL of your app), it may be that you failed to add 'accounts' to your list of `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py.

Comment: Q: "your subclass of UserenaBaseProfile or UserenaBaseProfile"? Aren't those two the same? Also, 'setting.py' should be 'settings.py'. Also, Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Hi Anuj, I fixed the two errors you pointed out.  Thanks for pointing them out.

Comment: This answer saved me a ton of time. I didn't realize I forgot to add the accounts app when I was following the installation instructions; totally overlooked it!

Answer (score 4):

Try following step:

1. In your settings.py file, add ’userena’, ’guardian’, ’easy_thumbnails’ to your INSTALLED_APPS tuple.
2. Then again in your settings.py file, add the following:

   ```
   AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (  
       'userena.backends.UserenaAuthenticationBackend',  
       'guardian.backends.ObjectPermissionBackend',  
       'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',  
   )  

   ANONYMOUS_USER_ID = -1
   ```

The above is used to get django-guardian working (another Django-Userena dependency that’s automatically installed to control permissions)

3. Next, create a new app for your Django-Userena app. In your Command Prompt shell, type: `python manage.py startapp accounts`. We are creating a new app for Django-Userena titled ‘accounts’.
4. Now add  `accounts` to your INSTALLED_APPS tuple in your settings.py file.
5. Copy the following into accounts/models.py:

   ```
   from django.contrib.auth.models import User  
   from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _  
   from userena.models import UserenaBaseProfile  

   class MyProfile(UserenaBaseProfile):  
       user = models.OneToOneField(User,unique=True,  
                     verbose_name=_('user'),related_name='my_profile')  
       favourite_snack = models.CharField(_('favouritesnack'),max_length=5)
   ```
6. Next add the following into settings.py file :

   ```
   AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'accounts.MyProfile'  

   LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/accounts/%(username)s/'  
   LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/signin/'  
   LOGOUT_URL = '/accounts/signout/'
   ```

The ‘accounts.MyProfile’ in AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE refers to the app ‘accounts’ containing the model class MyProfile as we defined earlier. The 3 login/logout URL statements tell Django where to have the URLs for Django-Userena to work.

7. Add the following into urls.py under the ‘urlpatterns’ tuple:

   ```
   (r'^accounts/', include('userena.urls')),
   ```
8. Configure your Django SMTP email settings to use Gmail in settings.py:

   ```
   EMAIL_USE_TLS = True  
   EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'  
   EMAIL_PORT = 587  
   EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'yourgmailaccount@gmail.com'  
   EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'yourgmailpassword'
   ```

   9. Go to your Command Prompt shell and type:

      `python manage.py check_permissions`

run /accounts/signin/