# Where do I create custom profile models for django-userena?

Tags: python, django, django-models, registration

I have a django app called `my_app` that uses `django-userena`; I am trying to create and use my own profile model by following the [django-userena installation documentation.](http://docs.django-userena.org/en/latest/installation.html#profiles)

In `my_app/models.py` I've added

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from userena.models import UserenaBaseProfile

class MyProfile(UserenaBaseProfile):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,
                                unique=True,
                                verbose_name=_('user'),
                                related_name='my_profile')
    favourite_snack = models.CharField(_('favourite snack'),
                                       max_length=5)
```

And then I've modified `my_app/settings.py` to include `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'my_app.MyProfile'` .

And yet, when I try to view any web page from my_app I get a `SiteProfileNotAvailable`. This error goes away if I move `MyProfile` to `accounts/models.py`

It seems like a bad idea to modify the `accounts` app in order to add custom fields. Am I wrong? Is there a way to add a custom profile module without modifying `accounts/models.py`?

Comment: You will find the answer in another thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809501/configuring-django-userena

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. For me it happened because I forgot to put `my_app` (or `accounts` as in the official docs) into `INSTALLED_APPS`.